# Spotify API - authentication via command line

Tags: python, spotipy

In order to access my playlists, I am using the following example code, which I got from [spotipy documentation](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) page:

```
import pprint
import sys
import os
import subprocess

import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util


client_id = 'my_id'
client_secret = 'my_secret'
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000/callback/'

scope = 'user-library-read'

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    username = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print "Usage: %s username" % (sys.argv[0],)
    sys.exit()

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri)

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
    for item in results['items']:
        track = item['track']
        print track['name'] + ' - ' + track['artists'][0]['name']
else:
    print "Can't get token for", username
```

when I run the script with `python myscript.py myusername`, I get this:

```
     User authentication requires interaction with your
            web browser. Once you enter your credentials and
            give authorization, you will be redirected to
            a url.  Paste that url you were directed to to
            complete the authorization.


Opening https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?scope=user-library-read&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fcallback&response_type=code&client_id=d3b2f7a12362468daa393cf457185973 in your browser


Enter the URL you were redirected to:
```

then, if I enter `http://localhost:8000/callback/`, I get the following error:

```
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/spotipy/util.py", line 86, in prompt_for_user_token
    token_info = sp_oauth.get_access_token(code)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 210, in get_access_token
    raise SpotifyOauthError(response.reason)
spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: Bad Request
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the same example code and ran into the same issues. But got it working by running a server on localhost first `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and then made my app's website `http://localhost:8000` and my redirect `http://localhost:8000` too. After that I opened a new terminal window and ran `python myscript.py my_user_name` the url then opened in my browser if it didn't open for you, you could just copy and paste the url link it gave you from this line in your terminal

```
Opening https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?scope=user-library-read&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fcallback&response_type=code&client_id=d3b2f7a12362468daa393cf457185973 in your browser
```

directly into your browser and you'll be greeted with a page that requests you give the app access to your account. After doing this the new url that you should copy and paste in the terminal will appear directly in the browser. You wont see anything happen afterwards because you need to print the token :

```
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(
    username, scope, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri)

if token:
  print "token: ", token
  sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
  # code 
else:
  print "Can't get token for", username
```